# Handling oAuth2 access_token expiration

Tags: html, jquery, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

After authentication with Google `oauth2.login` getting `access_token` and `expires_in`. Everithing going great till my token expires. After expiration, when I send again request for data with old token like that:

```
var URLHead = 'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql='
var URLTable = encodeURI('SELECT id,COUNT() FROM TABLE_ID')
var URLTail = '&access_token='+ old_token +'&jsonCallback=?'
var queryURL = URLHead + URLTable + URLTail
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: queryURL,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (d) {
    var max = d.table.rows[0].toString().substr(1)
    localStorage.setItem('cpage', Math.ceil(max / localStorage.getItem('delimeter')))
  },
  error: function(){alert('token_expired')}
})
```

working on success and giving nothing if token expired. All over the internet can't find clear example how to handle expiration? Shouold I count myself 3600 seconds and delete old_token or is there any elegant way to handle token expiration error?

Answer (score 0):

What does the response look like when the token has expired? The API is not necessarily going to throw an error, just a normal JSON response. The response probably contains something to say that the token has expired which you can therefore use to check on the fly.

Try:

```
success: function (d) {
 if(d.error){
   if(d.error == 'invalid_token'){
    alert('invalid_token');
   }
 } else {
  // local storage etc 
 }
}
```

or (with error handling) :

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44Az%20%E2%80%8BqT3Zg",
  type: "GET",
});

request.done(function(msg) {
 // complete
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

​
Heres the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MFe9d/

Comment: well I can catch only success. The only way I found to get JSON response is `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg`

Comment: Yes but the response will contain data telling you that your token has expired?

Comment: No. `success` is not running after token expires.

Comment: No. If you insert true token (check in [here](http://ft2json.appspot.com/api/samples.html)) even after it expires you will NOT get any response at all. But thanks for your help I think I'll handle it from here. Looks like the only way is var jqxhr_chkToken = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token='+ localStorage.getItem('token'),
    success: myFTAuth.google_chkToken,
  })

Comment: Have looked at my JS fiddle? I'm using the URL you gave that returns an error and my example works out if there is an error or not...

Comment: Yes sir! I checked it. You getting error because the token you insert - FAKE. put in there normal expired token and you'll see no error

Comment: Oh I see, I thought that was an expired therefore it was returning an error! Please try and be clearer in your comments.